# Is there a model with additive effects for always positive dependant variable?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, logarithm

When modeling a dependant variable always positive and continuous, models as log-transformed linear model or GLM with log link are generally used.
The log-transformed linear model  is : $\mathbb{E}[log(y)] = X\beta$
The GLM with log link model is : $log(\mathbb{E}[y]) = X\beta$
Thus, with both of them, the effects are no longer additives but multiplicatives.

I have two questions :
1) Is there a model with additive effects for always positive dependant variable ?
2) Why the change in relation effects (from additive to multiplicative) doesn't seem to be a problem for anyone ?